# Keep list open unless clicked or hovered off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery/JS function that shows a list when you hover over a button. However, when you hover off the button, the list does not show. I need the list to keep showing when you hover over it, and close when you hover off or click a link on the list.

How can I achieve this?
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wj6pguf2/

JQ

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var recent = ["Appel", "Aardbei", "Aardappelen", "Banaan", "Bananen", "Banana", "Druif"]
    $("#recent").hover(function() {
        $("#recentcomplete").empty();
        document.getElementById("recentcomplete").style.display = "block";
        recent.forEach(function(item) {
            $("#recentcomplete").append('<li><a href="#">' + item + '</a></li>');
        });
            }, function() {
        document.getElementById("recentcomplete").style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

HTML

```
        <button type="submit" name="recent" id="recent" style="max-width:150px;">snelkiezer</button>

        <ul id="recentcomplete" >
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the ID of the list to your hover call:

```
$("#recent, #recentcomplete").hover(function() {
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/g3rdye3w/)**

To close the list upon clicking a link, use:

```
$(document).on('click', '#recentcomplete a', function() {
    $('#recentcomplete').hide()
})
```

Comment: That's really nice and simple, thanks. How can I close it once a link is clicked?

Comment: It should close once you click a link since the link will take you to another page or location on this page. If you change the `#` you have now you'll see that. Do you need to keep the `#` URLs you have in your example?

Comment: Yes, It's gonna be a function to add the selected item to a database. So the link will not take you to another page.